# How add params to my form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<form method="post" class="search-form" action="?">
  <fieldset>
   <input class="search home_input_search" placeholder="Поиск" type="search" />
   <input  type="submit" class="subm but_search" value="" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have a form - search, this is layout and my task consistent in creation link to the controller with params like `Products/index?search_name=something`. And I dont know how I can transfer value textbox in my link.

Comment: oh, really dont know, its missclick maybe

Comment: You dont. You post the form and the value of the textbox is added if its a GET. Because you have not given your textbox `name` attribute, then nothing will post - add `name="search_name"` to the html

Comment: so you mean when i will get this field in my controller.. My main problem that had given in action="?" -> for example action="Home/Index?search=(and this field my search text box)"

Comment: If you have a controller with parameter `string search_name` (or a model containing a property with `string search_name`) then it will be bound correctly. But it should be `method="get"` (not post)

Comment: Suggest you look at the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999277/drop-downlist-search/33004055#33004055) for an example of implementing a search form

Answer (score 0):

Add onsubmit event handler to form, it should:

1. create Url with query string ?search_name= value from input
2. set window.location.href to created url
3. return false

EDIT: Of course, you can implement that in different way, the form is not needed in that case.

Comment: Why would you want to code this in Javascript while you just need two attributes on a form?

Comment: so how transfer to action jquery function yo:D
i can write like action="some_js_function()" should will be redirect to my ended link with my params? i think - no(

Comment: <form onsubmit="myFunction()">

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `input`s the `name` they should have on posting and set the right `action` on the `form`. The `name` on the input determines what the key will be in the URL (since you use the `GET` method). Setting the `action` on the `form` will indicate where to send it to.

```html
<form method="post" class="search-form" action="Products/index" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
   <input name="search_name" class="search home_input_search" placeholder="Поиск" type="search" />
   <input  type="submit" class="subm but_search" value="" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there it'll be better to call controller paramter "searchName" instead of "search_name". That corresponds with code conventions.

Next, when you call Proudcts/index?search_name=somethink in browser you are initiating GET request. GET requests have no body and communicate with query parameters.

When you create new form and submit 'em to the server you are initiating POST request (by default). Post request has the body-section which contains request parameters.

Then we should start from View. If you want to use query-string you should explicitly [create GET-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571988/form-get-with-value-in-mvc-route):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerMethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
}
```

Next you should add name attribute to your input with the same name as in the controller method parameter:

```
<input class="search home_input_search" name="searchName" placeholder="Поиск" type="search" />
```

Or you can use [HtmlHelper method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions_methods(v=vs.118).aspx) to generate html:

```
@Html.TextBox("searchName", string.Empty, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "search home_input_search" }, { "placeholder", "Поиск" } })
```

Finally you can have as many parameters as you need:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerMethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Label("Поиск")
    @Html.TextBox("searchName", string.Empty, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "search home_input_search" }, { "placeholder", "Поиск" } })
    @Html.Label("Включая вложенные")
    @Html.CheckBox("includeNested", true)
}
```

Comment: thx, helper decided my problem=)
he take base url like mysite.com and add to him controller and methodcontroller how dont doing html code.

if i now in mysite.com/home/method/ 
html add
mysite.com/home/method/method

Comment: Oh, I can't understand do you still have problems with routing. Note that Html.BeginForm is just generated html code and you can see real <form> code of your html page int the browser.

Comment: if i have already ?params=1 and i want add second like ?params=1&params2=2. What i need to do?

Comment: You can just add as many parameters as you need (but you have a limitation for query string length). Just add another one parameter to the controller's method and add another input with name explicitly or via HtmlHelper. You can add not only textboxes if you need to get other types (see the last link in my answer).

Comment: oh sorry maybe i put wrong question.. I have homepage where in head search textbox.
My controller with products have already params like ?category=1 and what i do, me need go to the ?category=1 and add search text like anythink. So, when i stay in category=1 me need just add second param. 

Me need take full link and concat with new param

Comment: @АлексейБалюк you can add hidden field to your form and set it from your model: @Html.Hidden("categoryId", Model.CurrentCategory). This code will generate <input type="hidden" name="categoryId" value="3" />